# Passing multiple iterable args to ProcessPoolExecutor.map using a partial

Tags: python

## Setup

I have a function set up to take in multiple keyword args:

```
def process(image, folder, param1, param2, param3):
    do_things
    return
```

And I have several combinations of param1/2/3 that I want to iterate through in a full permutation fashion (i.e. 1,4,7 then 1,4,8 until 3,6,9):

```
param1 = [1,2,3]
param2 = [4,5,6]
param3 = [7,8,9]
```

However, the `image` and `folder` remain the same, so I've set up a partial like so and wrapped it inside of a ProcessPoolExecutor map function:

```
with futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
    data = executor.map(
        partial(process,
            image=image,
            folder=folder,
        ),
        ...
    )
```

## Question

When I have 1 param for the function, and remove `param2` and `param3` from `process()`, the following single iterable works:

```
with futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
    data = executor.map(
        partial(process,
            image=image,
            folder=folder,
        ),
        [q for q in param1]
    )
```

But how do I pass in multiple iterable for the executor.map to work with?

## I've tried

```
with futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
    data = executor.map(
        partial(process,
            image=image,
            folder=folder,
        ),
        [q for q in param1],
        [q for q in param2],
        [q for q in param3],
    )
```

Both with and without specifying the function keyword name, but in either case I get a `TypeError: process() got multiple values for argument 'image'`

Also tried:

```
    with futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
    data = executor.map(
        partial(process,
            image=image,
            folder=folder,
        ),
        [i for i in product(param1, param2, param3)]
    )
```

The above givesthe error: `BrokenProcessPool: A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending.`

## Expected outcome

I want the executor.map to iterate through multiple iterables and pass them to the correct function keyword.

## **Code for Reproducible Error:**

```
from functools import partial
from concurrent import futures
from itertools import product

def new_fn(a, b, c):
    print(a, b, c)
    return (a, b, c)

a_static = 'Hi: '
b_it = ['b1', 'b2', 'b3']
c_it = ['c1', 'c2', 'c3']
p = [i for i in product(b_it, c_it)]

with futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
    data = executor.map(
        partial(new_fn, a=a_static), p
    )

data
```

Comment: send all `param` as list or dictionary - and then function will get it as single argument.

Comment: BTW: `[q for q in param1]` means the same as `list(param1)` or event `param1`.

Comment: BTW: `[i for i in product(param1, param2, param3)]` should gives the same result as `list(product(param1, param2, param3))` but in some situations it should works even as `product(param1, param2, param3)` ( without `list()`)

Comment: `product(param1, param2, param3)` creates tuples with 3 values and funciton may gets it as single argument, not as 3 separated arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never say exactly *how* you want to iterate through param1/2/3, so this is just a guess.

You can do what I think you want by changing the calling sequence of the `process()` function slightly and using the built-in [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function to *unzip* the data (as mentioned in the documentation).

Note how the built-in `partial()` function is being used — trying to pass it keyword arguments for positional ones, as you were attempting, was incorrect.

I also added the `if __name__ == '__main__':` guard needed to make Python multiprocessing code (also) work on Windows.

```
import concurrent.futures as futures
from functools import partial


def process(image, folder, params):
    param1, param2, param3 = params
    print(f'param1={param1}, param2={param2}, param3={param3}')


if __name__ == '__main__':

    image = 'image'
    folder = 'folder'

    param1 = [1, 2, 3]
    param2 = [4, 5, 6]
    param3 = [7, 8, 9]

    with futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
        data = executor.map(
            partial(process, image, folder),
            zip(*zip(param1, param2, param3))
        )

        for _ in data:
            ...
```

Output:

```
param1=1, param2=2, param3=3
param1=4, param2=5, param3=6
param1=7, param2=8, param3=9
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I was trying to make a full product permutation of all elements in params1/2/3, hence why I used product() [so process() would take 1,4,7 then 1,4,8 etc]. I'll try your solution and let you know how it goes

Comment: PeptideWitch: You changed your question while I was answering it — there was no use of `product()` in the earlier version(s).

Comment: Executing your code as-is on my lab book (with and without the main call) results in a `BrokenProcessPool: A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending.` I replaced `for _ in data` with `print([i for i in data])`

Comment: RE product change: Yes, I sought to clarify my intention - apologies if I jumped the gun

Comment: I tried the same solution by substituting the double zip with `product(param1, param2, param3)` - same `BrokenProcessPool` error. But I like the idea of unpacking the params within the function! I think we're 90% of the way there

Comment: PeptideWitch: Hmm, I don't get the `BrokenProcessPool ` when I run it. Regardless, I'll see if I can apply the unzipping "trick" in conjunction with `product()`. I'm using Python 3.8.2

Comment: Oh dear. I'm guessing you're using 3.8 given the f string evals? I'm on 3.7

Comment: PeptideWitch: You don't need to use `zip()` to do the product, just change the `zip(*zip(param1, param2, param3)` in my answer to `product(param1, param2, param3)` — again assuming I'm understanding what you want to do correctly (and ignoring the `BrokenProcessPool ` issue).

Comment: Thanks again - switched the `product()` back in but still getting the issue. I'll try moving away from jupyter lab, that might be causing some sort of issue

Comment: As an addendum, [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) specify that the ProcessPoolExecutor will not function properly inside of interactive python environments, so I'll find a workaround for this solution.

Comment: PeptideWitch: Glad to hear you've determined the cause of the `BrokenProcessPool`. Not working in "interactive python environments" just means an environment without a actual `__main__` .py script file that can be imported by subprocesses (due to the way Python does multiprocessing), so there's a very simple "workaround" - just put it in a file and execute that.