# ProcessPoolExecutor not working for function with multiple arguments - python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, multiprocessing

I have a dataframe `df_full` that I am trying to rewrite as a `dict()` while also doing some stuff over it.

```py
          agent     locations                       modal_choices        
0         agent_1   'loc1', 'loc2', 'loc3', 'loc2'  'mode_1', 'mode_1', 'mode_2', 'mode_3'
1         agent_2   'loc1', 'loc4', 'loc2', 'loc6'  'mode_2', 'mode_3', 'mode_2', 'mode_3'
```

I am currently facing a problem while trying to multiprocess the following function `format_dict()` knowing that I only want to iterate over the `agent` argument, the three others are supposed to be the same for each iterations. So I added the `partial()` parameter to "freeze" `df`, `dict_` and `list_` but the code returns me an empty dict and an empty list by the end and I don't understand why.
I suppose I haven't written the `executor.map()` properly. I tried following the methods shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61672749/passing-multiple-iterable-args-to-processpoolexecutor-map-using-a-partial) but it still doesn't return anything.

**What could be wrong with my code?**

I also printed the time taken by the following script to run with `time.perf_counter()` and compared it with what is given with `tqdm()` but the two values don't match. The iteration part is done in 7 seconds (tqdm) while the print of `time.perf_counter()` shows up after 2.3 minutes.

**What would explain the delay for the ending of the `with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:`?**

I am, unfortunately, still not an expert in python and this is the first time I'm trying to multiprocess something (as the `agent` list I am working with is massive and would take days to process...). Any help would be greatly appreciated! And please do tell me if informations are missing or if something is not explained properly, I'll edit the post right away.

---

```py
def format_dict(agent, df, dict_, list_):
    try:
        dict_[agent] = dict()

        toto_ = df.loc[df.agent_ID == agent]

        toto_mod = toto_['modal_choices'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.split(',')))
        toto_loc = toto_['locations'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.split(',')))

        for i in toto_mod:
            dict_[agent]['step_{}'.format(i)] = dict()
            dict_[agent]['step_{}'.format(i)]['mode']  = toto_mod[i].iloc[0]
            dict_[agent]['step_{}'.format(i)]['start'] = toto_loc[counter + 1].iloc[0]

        dict_[agent]['step_{}'.format(i)]['name']    = dict_agent_edt[agent]['step_0']['name']
        
    except ValueError:
        list_.append(agent)
        
    return dict_, list_


dict_name = dict()
list_name = list()

start = time.perf_counter()

agent = df_full['agent'][:1000]

with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    executor.map(partial(format_dict, df=df_full, dict_=dict_name, list_=list_name),
                 tqdm(agent), chunksize=50)
    
end = time.perf_counter()

print(f'It took {(end-start)/60} minutes.')
```

---

Following @Louis Lac's answer, I modified my script to avoid any concurrence but it still returns an empty dict.

```py
def format_dict(agent, df, dict_):
    try:
        dict_[agent] = dict()
        toto_ = df.loc[df.agent_ID == agent]

        (same stuff here)
        
    except ValueError:
        pass
        
    return dict_


start = time.perf_counter()

agents = df_full['agent'][:1000]
dict_name = {}

with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    executor.map(partial(format_dict, df=df_full, dict_=dict_name),
                 tqdm(agents), chunksize=50)

end = time.perf_counter()

print(f'It took {(end-start)/60} minutes.')
```

Comment: First, rename `agent = df_full['agent'][:1000]` to `agents` because it is misleading with the function argument `agent` (you iterate over multiple agents). Second, you return a tuple from `format_dict()` which you never use. Third, `format_dict()` will be executed in parallel, thus it should not mutate any shared state (`dict_`and `list_`) to avoid race conditions.  Remove those arguments and build the dictionary and the list serially after processing the dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

When using concurrency such as multithreading and multiprocessing, functions that are executed concurrently such as `format_dict` should not mutate shared state to avoid data races or the mutations should be synchronized.

You could for instance compute all your stuff concurrently first, then sequentially reduce the result into outputs (`dict_` and `list_`):

```py
def format_dict(agent, df):
    list_ = None
    try:
        dict_ = dict()

        toto_ = df.loc[df.agent_ID == agent]

        toto_mod = toto_['modal_choices'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.split(',')))
        toto_loc = toto_['locations'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.split(',')))

        for i in toto_mod:
            dict_['step_{}'.format(i)] = dict()
            dict_['step_{}'.format(i)]['mode']  = toto_mod[i].iloc[0]
            dict_['step_{}'.format(i)]['start'] = toto_loc[counter + 1].iloc[0]

        dict_['step_{}'.format(i)]['name'] = dict_agent_edt[agent]['step_0']['name']
        
    except ValueError:
        list_ = agent
        
    return dict_, list_

start = time.perf_counter()

agents = df_full['agent'][:1000]

with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    elements = executor.map(partial(format_dict, df=df_full),
                 tqdm(agents), chunksize=50)
  
dict_ = {}
list_ = []
for agent, (d, l) in zip(agents, elements):
  if l is not None:
    list_.append(l)
  dict_[agent] = d

end = time.perf_counter()

print(f'It took {(end-start)/60} minutes.')
```

Comment: I just tried this but it ends up taking as much time as it would if I ran the script sequentially. So I just tried to drop making the list ```list_``` altogether as I can deal with the "bad" keys of the dictionary later. But it still takes as much time as the sequential way and my method also doesn't return me anything. I've updated my post so you can see what I tried.

Comment: Oh sorry @Louis Lac, I inadvertently edited your answer instead of my question... (I just added something at the end so it shouldn't be a big problem).

Comment: I think your second try is still wrong as it still modify shared state: `dict_[agent] = dict()`. Take a look at my answer and try the proposed fix. Also, could you try two things: 1) a `ThreadPoolExecutor` instead and 2) use a `ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=1)`?

Comment: I have a question, I thought ```ProcessPoolExecutor``` was supposed to be used for CPU related stuff? There are a lot of calculus in my function so I thought it would have been appropriate to use it. Also, about the ```dict_[agent] = dict()``` statement: I tried following what you told me but it raises an error for the very first agent ```KeyError: 'agent_1'```. That's why I went back to what I first tried but I understand how it can be wrong. I'm not sure what I have to do to avoid the ```KeyError```.

Comment: Could you send a sample of df_full and the detail of the function dict_agent_edt so I can reproduce the issue?

Comment: And also what is `counter`.